# For Loop and The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, series, valueerror

Looked through the answers to similar queries here but still unsure. Code below produces:

```
     for i in range(len(df)):
            if df[0]['SubconPartNumber1'].str.isdigit() == False :
                df['SubconPartNumber1'] = df['SubconPartNumber1'].str.replace(',', '/', regex = True)
                df['SubconPartNumber1'] = df['SubconPartNumber1'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)-", '/', regex = True)
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: can u post same dataframe example as in some rows and how is df[0] working either you have 0 as columns or you will get key error because of that. and as a solution you can use apply function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas you can [avoid loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002) if possible. Your solution should be replace by `boolean mask` with `~` for invert instead `== False` and passed to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['SubconPartNumber1'].str.isdigit()
df.loc[~m, 'SubconPartNumber1'] = df.loc[~m, 'SubconPartNumber1'].str.replace(',', '/', regex = True).str.replace(r"\(.*\)-", '/', regex = True)
```

But because numeric has only numbers I think mask is not necessary here, also regex should be join by `|` for `or`, `regex=True` is default parameter, so should be omitted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SubconPartNumber1':['345','aaa,','(bbb)-ccc']})
print (df)
  SubconPartNumber1
0               345
1              aaa,
2         (bbb)-ccc

df['SubconPartNumber1'] = df['SubconPartNumber1'].str.replace(r",|\(.*\)-", '/')
print (df)
  SubconPartNumber1
0               345
1              aaa/
2              /ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
if df[0]['SubconPartNumber1'].str.isdigit() == False :
```

with this:

```
if df[0]['SubconPartNumber1'].str.isdigit().empty:
```

There are other methods besides `empty`, but I think this will get you what you want.

Comment: Answer is clearly wrong, `==False` is for invert mask or boolean, `.empty` is for test empty Series, DataFrame, so using here it has no sense.

Comment: Clearly you read the error the OP was getting that specifically states to use the `.empty` method?  Did you test it?